# The insulin protein of apes & chimpanzees

Tags: proteins, amino-acids, insulin

How many amino acids do the insulin protein of apes and chimanpzees compose of?!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! There are probably 20-30 extant species of apes (6 of them were sequenced; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_animal_genomes#Mammals)). It will be impossible to answer for every single species. Why do you say `apes & chimpanzees`. You are interested in all apes but in particular in chimpanzees? Why chimpanzee in particular (why not bonobo, human or a species of gorilla typically)? If you could give some background behind your interest it would be more likely people would find the question worth their time.

Comment: Chimpanzees are apes.

Answer (score 1):

On the Ensembl website you can find an easy way to compare genetic sequences of the available genome references, including the one of several primates.

Here a query example:
http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Compara_Alignments?align=822&db=core&g=ENSG00000254647&r=11%3A2159779-2161341

For protein sequences, check the Uniprot website. For insulin, this is the page you are looking for http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P01308
Check the paragraph "Similar proteins", there you will find all the links to retreive the insulin sequence from all the species for which we have sequencing data.